# setup of subdomain for email processing

Tags: domain-name-system

We use Win2003 Server with MS DNS.  Fairly new to DNS and can't seem to figure this out.

We have a client who has an A record pointed at an IP with a 3rd party service.  Now they want to be able to send & receive email via user@abc.domain.com using our service.

Currently his domain has a mx record pointing at our mail server and I want to know if I can set it up so that the will work through our service.

I have copied the record in here and changed the names etc to hopefully get some insight

Zone records - domain.com
;

@                       A   111.222.333.444
@                       MX  10  mail.emailhost.com.
abc                     A   999.888.777.666
www                     A   111.222.333.444

So the 3rd party is   abc.domain.com   and everything else is hosted through us.  He wants to know if he can have us setup email  user@abc.domain.com and run it through our service at mail.emailhost.com.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a new zone for abc.domain.com.

Add MX records into this zone which point to the mail server on your system.

Remove the abc A record from the zone for domain.com, and put it in this new zone file (for the sake of tidiness).  Obviously it will be `@ A ...` rather than `abc A` when homed in this subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he can. You have to add a MX record for  abc.domain.com that point to you mail.emailhost.com.

abc MX 10 mail.emailhost.com